# В чем разница между вводным словом и словом, употребляемым в значении вводного?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

В интернете встретил вопрос Галины Аванесовый: ["Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна", — можно ли доверять словарю Лопатина?](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/78363861)

Педагог по русскому языку Ирина Робертовна (участники форума слышали, наверняка, о ней) помимо ответа на ее вопрос, прокомментировала и слово **"наконец"** из ее вопроса.

По ее словам слово **"наконец"** не является вводным, а только наречием. Но в предложении может выполнять роль вводного. Поэтому в словарях **Кузнецова, Лопатина** допущена **грубейшая ошибка:** в них произошло смешение принадлежности слова к определённому морфологическому классу (части речи) и его синтаксической функции.

В добавок она пишет, что еще Ожегов  указывал *"вводн. сл. " только тогда, когда слово в предложении выполняло только функцию вводного, поэтому отнести его к какой-либо части речи не представлялось возможным (допустим, слово НАПРИМЕР).*

Открываю **Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949—1992(онлайн)**; там написано: **наконец — вводное.**

На мой взгляд, корректнее было бы говорить об омонимичности вводных слов и членов предложения, а не принадлежности того или иного слова к определенному морфологическому классу, которое может выполнять роль вводного слова только в предложении.

Даже Розенталь писал: "В зависимости от контекста одни и те же слова выступают то в качестве членов предложения, то в роли вводных слов (следовательно, не членов предложения)".

А что думаете вы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Однозначно указать частеречную принадлежность вводных слов пока невозможно, единого мнения нет, но в среде учёных их давно называют **модальными словами**.

Модальные слова — это слова или выражения, которые не имеют самостоятельного полноценного значения, но выражают отношение говорящего к сути высказывания. Они могут означать степень достоверности высказывания, эмоциональное отношение к сказанному, логическо-семантические связи между высказываниями.
**В обиходе модальные слова обычно называют вводными словами,** хотя это не совсем правильно. Как самостоятельная категория слов модальные слова были выделены  В. В. Виноградовым. Он рассматривал их как **нечто промежуточное между полноценными (знаменательными) и служебными частями речи**.

В языкознании модальные слова остаются предметом жарких споров, дискуссий, иногда даже пререканий. Их статус окончательно не определён; **в школьных учебниках модальные слова в качестве отдельной части речи, как правило, не выделяют. Иногда их рассматривают как подкласс наречий.**
Baлгинa H.C., Poзeнтaль Д.Э., Фoминa M.И. Coвpeмeнный pyccкий язык — M., 2002г. Иcтoчник:

http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/morfologia/modalnie-slova/modalnie-slova-kak-osobiy-razryad-slov-v-russkom-yazike/551/?n=551&q=463

В Русской корпусной грамматике читаем
(http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8):

> 5.2.4 Как особая часть речи нередко рассматриваются вводные (или модальные) слова. Это неизменяемые слова
> (производные от слов иных частей речи), выступающие в синтаксической  функции вводного слова: во-первых, итак, разумеется, вернее, дескать
> (всего подобных слов около трёхсот).  В русской грамматической традиции часть
> таких слов относилась к наречиям (видимо, вероятно, конечно), часть –
> к союзам (итак, во-первых), в словарях они нередко сопровождаются
> оговоркой «в значении вводного слова». Ряд авторов (Л.В. Щерба, В.Н.
> Сидоров) оставлял такие слова за пределами частеречной классификации.
> В.В. Виноградов рассматривал их в качестве особого разряда [Виноградов
> 1947], в качестве особой части речи они выделены и в Грамматическом
> словаре А.А. Зализняка [Зализняк 1977]. Высказывались и сомнения в
> правомерности выделения вводных слов в особую часть речи, на основании
> того, что вводная конструкция может формироваться словосочетанием типа
> короче говоря, не меняющим при этом частеречной принадлежности
> [Буланин 1976: 88]. *(13) Пожалуй, лишь школьники Вязников (видимо,
> сказывается влияние Москвы с её высоким уровнем жизни) и
> Красногвардейского озвучили более высокие материальные запросы ― в
> этих населённых пунктах около 60% выпускников претендуют на заработки
> выше 10 тысяч в месяц. [«Человек» 2005]*
>
> 5.3 Частеречный инвентарь Грамматического словаря А.А. Зализняка и разметки Корпуса
>
> В Грамматическом словаре А.А. Зализняка [Зализняк
> 1977] в качестве особых частей речи выделены предикативы, а также
> вводные слова.
> Всего частей речи в Грамматическом словаре, таким образом,
> четырнадцать.

Так что  **вводное слово** вполне корректно называть частью речи. Ирина Робертовна, видимо, где-то упустила из виду эти лингвистические дискуссии в последние годы, а так как она **учитель от Бога**, то строго следит, чтоб ученики не путались с терминологией. К сожалению, школьная и студенческая терминология научной среды не всегда совпадают. Модальных слов в словаре для школьников нет.

Comment: Вводные слова имеют разное значение, не только модальное. Они обозначают источник сообщения, а также используются для оформления речи (порядок рассуждения, выделение главного, подведение итогов и др.).  Или это  тоже модальное значение (такое расширенное)? Вообще, как мне кажется, нашу гуманитарную среду неплохо было бы дополнить математиками. Может быть, они тогда не проводили бы дискуссии, а создавали ясные и строго обоснованные теории, подходящие  для всех пользователей языка, а не только для своих собственных замкнутых сообществ..

Comment: Некоторые лингвисты вводные слова, указывающие на источник сообщения, тоже относят к модальным.

Comment: Это пожалуйста, можно относить что угодно и куда угодно.  Но предварительно надо дать новое определение для модальных слов. Сейчас модальные слова определяются примерно так: Модальные слова в русском языке – это категория слов , которые выражают не само действие, а отношение к нему,  соответствие высказывания действительности. Различают объективную и субъективную модальность и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

**Морфология** ― это грамматическое учение о слове, в частности учение о принадлежности слов **к определенной части речи**. Надо сказать, что классификация частей речи **менялась:** части речи и частицы речи, знаменательные и служебные слова, выделение междометий и звукоподражательных слов в отдельную группу и т.д. Но никогда **вводные слова не рассматривались как часть речи.**

**Вводные слова ― это тема синтаксиса,** то есть раздела грамматики, изучающего строй речи, **роль слов в предложении**, его **синтаксическую функцию.**  Вводные слова (и вставные конструкции) не являются членами предложения.

Возможен **переход** слов из одной части речи в другую. Одно и то же слово (например, наречие) может быть обстоятельством или вводным словом, то есть **выполнять разные грамматические функции**.

Но **невозможен переход из части речи в синтаксическую функцию**, такое  утверждение не имеет смысла, так как эти понятия не пересекаются.

Вывод: ***наконец*** (как часть речи) ―  это **наречие, не вводное слово.**

Comment: В словарях ошибка?

Comment: Нужно знать, какой классификацией частей речи они пользовались. В вузовском учебнике по морфологии (2009 год) приведено несколько классификаций, последняя - в Грамматике-80. Может быть, они изобрели свою особую классификацию?  А если пользоваться существующей, то в словарях корректно говорить так: употребляется в функции вводного слова, а не является вводным словом.

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, что пишет корпусная грамматика.

Comment: А там разве в разделе "Части речи" есть материал о вводных словах?

Comment: <....>допускается существование слов, не подпадающих под частеречную классификацию (да, нет, ***вводные слова***), хотя в целом эта позиция не ***получила поддержки в русистике*** [Князев 2001].

Comment: Вводные слова являются омонимичными  различным частям речи. Вот я о чем говорю.

Comment: Вашей фразы я не понимаю. У нас многие слова соотносятся с различными частями речи, но это не значит, что они не попадают под частеречную классификацию. Получится, что слово "наконец" то попадает под классификацию,  то не попадает.  Не нужно никому такое смешение понятий. У меня для этой темы есть образное представление: "актер и его роли". Что касается вводных слов, то я бы сказала, что это просто обособленные слова и обороты, имеющие  определенную тематику. Вот и всё их отличие от других обособленных членов. Всё это чистый синтаксис, к морфологии не имеющий отношение.

Comment: Вводные слова как лексико-грамматический класс  имееют внешнее сходство с другими частями речи. Прочитайте про модальные слова.

Comment: Дело не в том, что слово то подпадает, то не подпадает под частеричную классификицию, а в том, что граница между ними зыбкая.

Comment: Граница между многими словами зыбкая.  Вот "первый" - это грамматическое прилагательное, "тысяча" - грамматическое существительное, в разряд грамматических числительных их не пускают. У Розенталя перечисляется целый ряд слов, сходных по семантике с вводными словами, но которые не обособляются. Семантика, синтаксическая роль - это входит в характеристику части речи, но основным показателем является МОРФОЛОГИЯ.  Это - принципиальный фактор, позволяющий как-то ориентироваться  в зыбкой неопределенности.

Comment: И какие это слова у Розенталя?

Comment: Примечание. Не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми словами и словосочетания: авось, буквально, будто, вдобавок, в довершение, вдруг, ведь, в конечном счете, вот, вряд ли, всё-таки, даже, едва ли, исключительно, именно, как будто, как бы, как раз, к тому же, между тем, небось, по предложению, по постановлению, по решению, приблизительно, примерно, притом, почти, поэтому, просто, решительно, словно, якобы и др.Источник: http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxvi.html#sect100.1

Comment: Заметьте, названы или служебные слова (они не несут самостоятельной информации), или наречия, которые выполняют роль членов предложения - эти категории не включаются в разряд вводных (кроме частицы мол, потому что она замещает исходное молвит).

Answer (score 1):

Русская корпусная грамматика: При выделении частей речи возникает множество проблемных мест, связанных с морфологической и семантической разнородностью традиционных и интуитивно выделяемых классов. В ряде трактовок выделяются как части речи, не включенные в данный список и дополняющие его (вводное слово, различные подклассы местоимений и местоименных слов, предикатив (см.), причастие), так и объединяющие несколько частей речи из данного списка в одну (адъектив, субстантив, неизменяемые слова и т. п.).

**Многопризнаковый (лексико-грамматический) подход**
Подход, в русистике связанный прежде всего с именем В.В. Виноградова [Виноградов 1947] и его школой (предшественником его был Л.В. Щерба [Щерба 1928]), не игнорируя морфологических параметров, учитывает при выделении частей речи также синтаксические свойства сочетаемость и лексические (семантические) характеристики (как самостоятельные критерии, а не просто как свойство класса, выделяемого по морфологическим критериям), а часть речи рассматривает как лексико-грамматический класс.При таком подходе часть речи задаётся сочетанием нескольких признаков и носит «многомерный» характер. Так, «прилагательное» – это класс слов, которые:
a) обозначают признак предмета, не связанный с изменением во времени (в отличие от глагола, обозначающего динамическую ситуацию);
b) имеют словоизменительные грамматические категории рода, числа и падежа;
c) имеют прототипическую синтаксическую функцию согласуемого определения при существительном (в школьной формулировке, отвечает на вопрос «какой?»).

В рамках этого подхода по синтаксическому признаку удается провести границу между неизменяемыми служебными частями речи (союзы, частицы, предлоги), по семантическому признаку – выделить в отдельные классы местоимения и числительные в широком понимании (включающем местоимения-прилагательные и порядковые числительные) и т. п. Многопризнаковый подход допускает неоднозначный статус (полифункциональность) слов (например, весело – краткое прилагательное, наречие и предикатив; вот – наречие и частица). У некоторых авторов (Л.В. Щерба, В.Н. Сидоров) допускается существование слов, не подпадающих под частеречную классификацию (да, нет, вводные слова), хотя в целом эта позиция не получила поддержки в русистике [Князев 2001].

При многопризнаковом подходе различные критерии в разной степени применимы к традиционно выделяемым частям речи, что приводит к неоднозначности и непоследовательности классификации: одни части речи являются внутренне гетерогенными по тому или иному признаку, другие по ряду признаков слабо отделены от других (см. п. 4 Применимость частеречных критериев, [Князев 2001], [Евтюхин 2008]). Кроме того, синтаксические функции всех основных частей речи, хотя среди них и можно выделить базовые, достаточно разнообразны и не подчиняются жёстким ограничениям.

Источник: http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8